# Got Unsupported Media Type when calling web service from PL/SQL

Tags: c#, web-services, plsql

> I wrote some PLSQL code to consume my web service created in my local PC, but I always got a Unsupported Media Type exception, the exception code is 415. please see my code below:
>
> PLSQL:

```
declare
   l_param_list  varchar2(512);
   l_http_request UTL_HTTP.req;
   l_http_response UTL_HTTP.resp;
   l_response_text varchar2(32000);
   l_soap_request varchar2(32000);
begin
-- service's input parameters
   l_soap_request := '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <add xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <firstNum>3</firstNum>
      <secondNum>4</secondNum>
    </add>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';
--http://localhost:64955/Service1.asmx?op=add
--16.158.161.7
dbms_output.put_line('length of l_soap_request :' || length(l_soap_request));
dbms_output.put_line('l_soap_request : ' || l_soap_request);
-- prepareint Request...
   l_http_request := UTL_HTTP.begin_request ('http://localhost:64955/Service1.asmx'
                                            ,'POST'
                                            ,UTL_HTTP.HTTP_VERSION_1_1);

--...set header's attributes
UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_request,'Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');
UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_request,'Content-Type', length(l_soap_request));
UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_request,'SOAPAction','http://tempuri.org/add');
--...set input parameters
UTL_HTTP.write_text(l_http_request, l_soap_request);

-- get response and obtain received value
l_http_response := UTL_HTTP.get_response(l_http_request);

dbms_output.put_line('Response Received');
dbms_output.put_line('________');
dbms_output.put_line('Status Code : '||l_http_response.status_code);
--UTL_HTTP.read_text(l_http_response, l_response_text);
 dbms_output.put_line('Reason Phase : '||l_http_response.reason_phrase);
--dbms_output.put_line(l_response_text);
--dbms_output.put_line('test1');
utl_http.read_text(l_http_response,l_response_text);
dbms_output.put_line('Response : ');
dbms_output.put_line(l_response_text);
--finalizing
UTL_HTTP.end_response(l_http_response);

exception
   when UTL_HTTP.end_of_body then
        UTL_HTTP.end_response(l_http_response);
        dbms_output.put_line('test2');

end;
```

> Web service was created by .NET in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace Calculator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Service1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public string add(string firstNum, string secondNum)
        {
            int p1 = Convert.ToInt32(firstNum);
            int p2 = Convert.ToInt32(secondNum);
            return (p1 + p2).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

> Can anybody help me troubleshoot what's wrong with my code or media type, what is the correct media type or how to know the correct one is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting your content-type with the length

```
UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_request,'Content-Type', length(l_soap_request));
```

Instead you should do:

```
UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_request,'Content-Length', length(l_soap_request));
```

Comment: Oh, MGD, that's my mistake. Thanks for your help.